# Integrate a prebuilt .a into my Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, static-libraries, linker-errors

I'm trying to integrate a prebuilt a static c library (a .a library )into my Xcode 5 project. But it failed and returned tons of   ***Apple Mach-O linker errors***. What I did is I added the **Library Search Path** to correct path and added the **Other C flags**, **Other C++ flags** as something like -lmylib ( the lib file name is libmylib.a). I remembered it worked in my previous Xcode which using GCC.

Can anybody advise what I should do to fix the problem. Thanks.

**Edit:**

By adding these flags to Linker flag solved the problem. But I have another issue. The .a built for normal simulator doesn't work for the one with 64 bit. How should I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried other linker flag -ObjC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad. Add the flag to the wrong place. Should add to Other Linker Flag.